# Pagebreak (newpage) at the end of the table with Longtable

Tags: longtable

I'm using a Longtable (and Longtabu) inside tcolorbox, but longtable generates a pagebreak (newpage) at the end of the table. Everything is perfect. There are no errors. LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s) in (Miktex)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper,spanish]{book}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl,enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.59cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{shadowtext} %Paquete Sombras
\usepackage{type1cm} % Paquete tamaño de fuente
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=2cm, shadow,textsize=scriptsize]{todonotes}
\usepackage[most,many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,verbose,
tmargin=2.5cm,
bmargin=2cm,
lmargin=4cm,
rmargin=2cm
}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[perpage,ragged]{footmisc}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package comman
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\tt\color{black},
}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}% adds leader dots from chapter titles to page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}% adds dot after section title in ToC
%----------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{azulo}{RGB}{0,163,243}
%\definecolor{azulm}{RGB}{0,109,240}
\definecolor{azulc}{RGB}{191,233,251}
\definecolor{lgray}{gray}{0.85}
%\definecolor{azulo}{RGB}{0,153,255}
%\definecolor{azulm}{RGB}{0,109,240}
%\definecolor{azulc}{RGB}{222,243,253}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\partname}{PARTE}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APÉNDICE}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CAPÍTULO} % para ’book’
\renewcommand{\bibname}{BIBLIOGRAFÍA} % para ’book’
%----------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{titlebgdark}{RGB}{0,163,243}
\definecolor{titlebglight}{RGB}{191,233,251}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            toggle enlargement=evenpage,
      enhanced,
      colback=titlebgdark,
      boxrule=0.25cm,
      colframe=titlebglight,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
      leftrule=0pt,
      rightrule=0pt,
      fontupper=\color{white}\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{24}{36}\selectfont, %Título de capítulos principales
      enlarge left by=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin, 
      enlarge right by=-\paperwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,
      width=\paperwidth, 
      left=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, 
      right=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth,
      top=0.6cm, 
      bottom=0.6cm,
      overlay={
        \node[
          fill=titlebgdark,
          draw=titlebglight,
          line width=0.15cm,
          inner sep=0pt,
          text width=1.8cm,
          minimum height=1.8cm,
          align=center,
          font=\color{white}\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{32}{36}\selectfont %Número del capítulo
        ] 
        (chapname)
        at ([xshift=-4cm]frame.north east)
        {\thechapter};
        \node[font=\small,anchor=south,inner sep=2pt] at (chapname.north)
        {\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename};  
      } 
    ]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            toggle enlargement=evenpage,
      enhanced,
      colback=titlebgdark,
      boxrule=0.25cm,
      colframe=titlebglight,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
      remember as=title,
      leftrule=0pt,
      rightrule=0pt,
      fontupper=\color{white}\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{24}{36}\selectfont, %Títulos de Capítulos iniciales
      enlarge left by=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin, 
      enlarge right by=-\paperwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,
      width=\paperwidth, 
      left=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, 
      right=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth,
      top=0.6cm, 
      bottom=0.6cm, 
    ]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.eps}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\def\UrlFont{\rm}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\tcbset{enhanced,colback=azulc,colframe=azulo,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\newcommand{\seccion}[1]
{
\begin{tcolorbox}[toggle enlargement=evenpage,frame hidden,colback=azulo,left=0mm,top=-1.2mm,bottom=-1.2mm,arc=0mm]
\color{white} \section{#1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\newcommand{\subseccion}[1]
{
\subsection{#1}
}
\newcommand{\cuadro}[2]
{
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=#1]
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------
%En Casa: \newcommand{\linea}[1]{\noindent\makebox[12.55cm]{\color{azulo} \rule{15.55cm}{1.2pt}}}
%En la oficina:
\newcommand{\linea}[1]{\noindent\makebox[14.51cm]{\color{azulo} \rule{15.55cm}{1.3pt}}}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\link}[1]{{\small \textcolor{blue}{\protect\url{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\linkf}[1]{{\footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{\protect\url{#1}}}}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
%----------------------------------------------------------
%Personalizando las secciones
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\tcbox[toggle enlargement=evenpage, tcbox raise base,frame hidden,colback=azulo,left=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,right=0mm,arc=0mm]{\color{white} \thesection}}{2pt}{\shadowoffset{0.5pt} \shadowcolor{lgray}
\large \bfseries \shadowtext{\textcolor{azulo}{#1}}}
%----------------------------------------------------------
%Personalizando las secciones
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{\color{azulo} \shadowoffset{0.5pt} \shadowcolor{lgray} \shadowtext{\thesubsection}}{2pt}{\shadowoffset{0.5pt} \shadowcolor{lgray} \bfseries \shadowtext{\textcolor{azulo}{#1}}}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{\color{azulo} \shadowoffset{0.5pt} \shadowcolor{lgray} \shadowtext{\thesubsubsection}}{2pt}{\shadowoffset{0.5pt} \shadowcolor{lgray} \bfseries \shadowtext{\textcolor{azulo}{#1}}}

%Comando \shadow
\newcommand{\shadow}[1]
{
\shadowoffset{0.5pt} \shadowcolor{lgray} \shadowtext{\textcolor{azulo}{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\azul}[1]
{
\textcolor{azulo}{#1}
}
%Configuración de Viñetas
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\Large $\blacktriangleright$}
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bf \color{azulo} #1}}
%Contador
\newcounter{contador} % Nuevo contador
\setcounter{contador}{0}
\addtocounter{contador}{1}
\newcommand{\est}{\stepcounter{contador}{Estrategia \thechapter.\thecontador}}%


\addto\captionsspanish{%
   \renewcommand\contentsname{Contenido}
    }
\addto\captionsspanish{%
   \renewcommand\bibname{Bibliografía}
    }
\addto\captionsspanish{%
   \renewcommand\tablename{Tabla}
    }

    \addto\captionsspanish{%
   \renewcommand\figurename{Figura}
    }
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\makeatletter
\let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@none
\makeatother

%Comando \hito
%----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\hito}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.001\textwidth} p{0.95\textwidth}}
\mbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8,trim={0 0.1mm 0 0.6mm},clip]{icon/hito.eps}} & \textit{#1}
\end{tabular}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
.
.
.

\hito{Se debe contar con un espacio propicio para realizar esta actividad, este se les presenta a los aprendices para que realicen las respectivas dimensiones del mismo. Se indican con cuáles recursos cuenta la Tecnoacademia y la limitación que se tiene en los recursos, para que los aprendices propongan alternativas de bajo costo.}

    \captionof{table}{Características de plantas adaptables a las condiciones ambientales en la Tecnoacademia Ibagué. Fuente:}
        \label{tabla:est_33_1}
    {\footnotesize
        \taburulecolor{azulo}
        \arrayrulewidth=0.8pt
    \begin{longtabu}{|p{5.3em}|p{5em}|p{4.3em}|p{4.3em}|p{6.3em}|p{7.3em}|}
        \hline
        \rowfont \bfseries {Nombre Común} & {Nombre Científico} & {Distancia entre plantas} & {Alto de la planta} & {Tipo de riego} & {Tipo de suelo}\\
    \hline
        Orégano & \textit{Origanum vulgare Hirtum} & 15 cm & 12 a 18 in (pulgadas) & Dependiendo del tipo de suelo, regar cada 3 a 4 días & Sueltos, arcillosos, francos, permeables y ricos en materia orgánica \\
    \hline
        Romero & \textit{Rosmarinus officinalis} L. & 30 cm & 0,5 a 2 m & Una vez por semana & Calcáreos, con pH entre 5 y 8, bien drenados y ligeros \\
    \hline
        Tomillo & \textit{Thymus vulgaris} & 15 cm & 15 a 30 cm & Una vez cada 3 a 10 días & Suelos secos, calizos y rocosos \\
    \hline
        Menta & \textit{Mentha x Piperita L.} & De 20 a 30 cm & 40 a 80 cm & Dos a tres veces por semana & Suelos fértiles profundos con un pH cercano a 7 y un drenaje muy bueno \\
    \hline
        Albahaca & \textit{Ocimum basilicum L.} & 15 a 30 cm & 50 cm & Una vez al día & Suelos ricos, sueltos y con buen drenaje \\
    \hline
        Hierbabuena & \textit{Mentha sativa} & 25 cm & 40 cm & Cada cuatro días & Suelos ligeros, ricos en materia orgánica y con cierta humedad \\
    \hline
        Cilantro & \textit{Coriandrum sativum} & 15 cm & 15 a 20 cm & Una vez por semana & Suelos profundos y fértiles con buen drenaje y buena calidad de retención de agua \\
    \hline
        \nopagebreak
    \end{longtabu}
}

Texto de prueba.

\begin{enumerate}[font=\bf,start=2]
    \item \textbf{Comunicación}
Una vez desarrollada la actividad, cada grupo presentará su informe con gráficos y diseños realizados para su análisis y discusión en conjunto (aprendices e instructor). Se debe promover una discusión y participación permanente para que los aprendices argumenten las decisiones tomadas y el trabajo desarrollado. En esta fase el instructor promueve la participación y discusión de los aprendices con preguntas orientadoras y generadoras tales como:

\begin{itemize}
    \item ¿Qué piensan de los diseños de sus compañeros?
    \item ¿Por qué su diseño debería ser construido, y qué lo hace mejor a los demás?
    \item ¿Por qué en términos de costo es óptimo su diseño?
    \item ¿Qué tipo de plantas escogieron y por qué?
    \item ¿Qué variables consideraron para el diseño de la huerta?
    \item ¿Cómo estimó la extensión de terreno necesario para la elaboración del diseño?
\end{itemize}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code demonstrating the problem, that we can play with?

Comment: Don't show a fragment. Show a complete (but small) document, that we can try out.

Comment: It is very long (a book). Show some elements of the preambule.

Comment: I am sorry but fragments of code ending `...` are impossible to debug, please make a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: Show the preambule complete and screenshots.

Comment: Everything is perfect. There are no errors. LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s) in (Miktex)